# Kinvey data being loaded in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kinvey

I m have a problem with my RecyclerView. I m trying to populate it with a list of friends names, however when i launch my fragment friends are not loaded. On the other side friends are loaded if i m entering debug mode.

My code:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mKinveyClient = KinveyUtils.getClient(getContext());
    mFriends = getUserFriends();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friend_list, container, false);


    // Set the adapter
  if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
      mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FriendRecyclerViewAdapter(mFriends));
    }
    return view;
}

 private ArrayList<ArrayMap> getUserFriends() {
    return (ArrayList<ArrayMap>) mKinveyClient.user().get(KinveyConstants.FRIENDS);
}
```

I feel like the friends are loading too slow, but all the needed data should be already in app by this time. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think you need to get friends in a background thread. And on completion of that you need to set the adapter.

Comment: This is correct.  You are resolving getUserFriends() synchronously in the main thread of your program.   Getting this to run in a background thread will allow your main thread to run smoothly.   Also, handling the call asynchronously by using http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/reference/api/reference/com/kinvey/android/AsyncAppData.html  should improve your performance somewhat dramatically.